# How to speed up dynamically adding user controls in wp7

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, grid

I have a page in my WP7 app that I build dynamically. I create and add 60 user controls to a grid and it takes around 5 seconds. I need to find a way of speeding this up.

The process is as follows:

1. Create user control
2. Add new grid row definition
3. Set the value of the control row property
4. Add the control to the grid.Children collection.

It is step 4 that is taking the time. I'm guessing that each time I do this the visual tree is getting re-built.

Is there any way of telling the grid to only re-build the visual tree after I have finished updating the children collection?

Or is there another better way of doing this?

**UPDATE: The List Picker control from the WP7 Toolkit was causing the problem. When I changed to one I wrote myself the time taken to display the page on a phone reduced from 25 seconds to 1 second.**

Comment: I would recommend using a StackPanel and the controls will be arranged automatically, rather than going the GridRow way.

Comment: I tried replacing the grid with a stack panel and it didn't improve performance at all. I believe that each time I add a control to the parent the visual tree gets re-calculated whether the parent is a stack panel or a grid. I need a way of telling the page to not rebuild until I tell it to or a way of adding all the controls in one go. I tried creating a UIElementCollection so I could fill it with controls then pass the whole thing to the Children collection but I get an error when I try and create one (as the constructor is internal).

Comment: You could try using a StackPanel bound to an ObservableCollection containing your UserControl objects. Initially set the ObservableCollection property to null, then add all UserControls to another ObservableCollection. Once you're done assign the second ObservableCollection to the bound property, then fire a NotifyPropertyChanged event to notify the page to update. If the collection never changes after initial creation you can replace the ObservableCollection with a List.

Comment: What property of the StackPanel should I bind the ui collection to?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of ListBox, not StackPanel. Ended up typing the latter after reading Dennis' earlier comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The/your aim is to try and reduce the number of times you update the visualtree.

A few suggestions:

- Try including (some of) the items in the page by default but just change their visibility depending on what you need.
- Build the whole grid in code and add it to the page in one go (rather than a line at a time)
- Depending on your content, you could try using a ListBox and alternating the template used for each row to get different content displayed.

The technique which will be best for you will depend on what you're actually adding to the UI. You'll need to test to see what is best for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Matt. Thought number 2 might do the trick so I created a grid, added all controls then added the grid to parent grid on page. No change. I tested it on phone and is taking 25 seconds to display the page!

Comment: Trying a ListBox now. Making a big difference. Down from 25 to 10 secs. I'm guessing the virtualizing stack panel built into the ListBox is helping here.

Answer (score 1):

If the UI virtualization (i.e. ListBox) helped, the problem must be in your controls. Templating, bindings, converters, using Xaml instead of C# code, unnecessary Xaml constructs (such as element names), overcomplicated visual tree (e.g. unneeded grids) etc. - those are the things that can degrade the performance.

If you suspect incremental visual tree rebuilds (I don't think so), then simply debug MeasureOverride/ArrangeOverride methods.

I guess [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Performance.aspx) might give you more tips. I described there how we optimized a similarly complex control - MonthCalendar with 126 sub-controls. Control load time decreased approx. 5x!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think you are correct - the listbox is hiding the problem, not fixing it. My user controls are very simple. Most of them are a textblock and a textbox arranged in a grid. The user control that is used the most contains the list picker control from the toolkit. I will try and replace this with a text box temporarily to see if this is causing the problem. Besides the user controls everything is generated by code. There are no bindings, templates or converters.

Comment: I would start by analyzing the visual tree using TreeHelper.Dump(). More often than not you will find a lot of unnecessary constructs. And don't forget the time measurement - you need to have an objective measure.

Comment: Looks like it was the List Picker control that was causing the problem. I wrote my own and it now takes 1 sec even after I went back to a grid.